# How to convert characters such as \xe2\x80\x99 to normal apostrophe in html string

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I have an html string like this "li Convenient \xe2\x80\x93 Pre-measured Bleach tablets /li"

How can I convert it properly while still preserving html tags in python? I want to do it for any of these characters not just those that represent an apostrophe.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in javascript perhaps?  Since it's an html string the goal is to display as is on a web page but non-ascii characters such as \xe2\x80\x93 need to be converted properly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, but to decode a byte string you could do this:

```
bstring = b"li Convenient \xe2\x80\x93 Pre-measured Bleach tablets /li"
string = bstring.decode('utf-8')
print(string)
>> 'li Convenient – Pre-measured Bleach tablets /li'
```

Comment: Thanks that helps but what if i have: 

value = "<li> Convenient \xe2\x80\x93 Pre-measured Bleach tablets </li>"
bstring = value.encode()
string = bstring.decode('utf-8')
print(string)

>><li> Convenient â Pre-measured Bleach tablets </li>

It doesn't convert the same way.  What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that when you put \xe2\x80\x93 inside quotation ("") \xe2 translates to â. That's why \xe2\x80\x93 isn't decoded properly into en-dash (–).